# ERR into railway deploy JS project

Tags: javascript, railway

I try deploy my API project into railway but I get an error

> nodemon src/config/server.js

[nodemon] 3.0.1

[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`

[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*

[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json

[nodemon] starting `node src/config/server.js`

node:internal/errors:478

ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/app/src/middleware/inputValidationMiddleware.js' imported from /app/src/routes/authRoute.js

at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)

at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:330:11)

at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:907:10)

at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1115:11)

at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)

at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:837:30)

at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)

at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)

at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {

code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'

}

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

then go to the Files research to found what problem

InputValidationMiddleware.js

```
 static validateLoginInput(req, res, next) {
    const { email, password, userName } = req.body;
    const query = email ? email : userName;

    if (validator.isValidEmail(query)) {
      const emailErrors = validator.validateEmail(email);
      if (emailErrors.length > 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: "Email is invalid",
        });
      }
    } else {
      const userNameErrors = validator.validateUserName(userName);
      if (userNameErrors.length > 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          message: "Username is invalid",
        });
      }
    }
```

and get the authRoute.js

```
import { Router } from "express";
import authController from "../controllers/authController.js";
import InputValidationMiddleware from "../middleware/inputValidationMiddleware.js";

const router = Router();

/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/register:
 * post:
 * summary: Register a new user
 * description: Register a new user
 * requestBody:
 * content:
 * application/json:
 * schema:
 * type: object
 * properties:
 * userName:
 * type: string
 * email:
 * type: string
 * password:
 * type: string
 * required:
 * - userName
 * - email
 * - password
 * responses:
 * 201:
 * description: User created successfully
 * 409:
 * description: User already exists
 * 500:
 * description: Internal server error
 * */

router.post(
  "/register",
  InputValidationMiddleware.validateRegisterInput,
  authController.createUser
);

/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/login:
 * post:
 * summary: Login a user
 * description: Login a user
 * requestBody:
 * content:
 * application/json:
 * schema:
 * type: object
 * properties:
 * userName:
 * type: string
 * email:
 * type: string
 * password:
 * type: string
 * required:
 * - email
 * - password
 * responses:
 * 200:
 * description: User logged in successfully
 * 401:
 * description: Invalid email or password
 * 500:
 * description: Internal server error
 * */
router.post(
  "/login",
  InputValidationMiddleware.validateLoginInput,
  authController.loginUser
);

export default router;
```

can anyone help me to catch the error ??

Maybe model not found or files but it all here not missing

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there might be a problem with your **InputValidationMiddleware.js** file. It would be better if you provided more details to this file, since it looks like you could export it incorrectly. Also, my suggestion is that you defined `validateLoginInput` function in some class, taking into account a `static` keyword.

Anyway, in case if it's just a single function then you should rewrite it like this:

```
function validateLoginInput(req, res, next) {
   // your code here
};

export default validateLoginInput;
```

Then import it like this:

```
import validateLoginInput from "../middleware/inputValidationMiddleware.js";
```

But if you have some sort of a class like `InputValidationMiddleware` for instance, then you would have to export your class using `export default` before its definition and leave the import statement as it is in your **authRoute.js** file.

Comment: still the error where can I edit railway.yml ?